# I keep getting this error when I'm running PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell-4.0

When I run this PowerShell script

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$path1 = Get-ItemProperty -PSPath IIS:\Sites\CompassSvcQA-Red\R4\CompassSettings

Set-Location "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
.\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" $path1.physicalPath -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
```

I'm getting this error:

> Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does
>   not exist. At line:2 char:10
>   + $path1 = Get-ItemProperty -PSPath IIS:\Sites\CompassSvcQA-Red\R4\CompassSettings
>   +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (IIS:String) [Get-ItemProperty], DriveNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Can't find the drive. The drive called 'IIS' does not exist."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392696/getting-cant-find-the-drive-the-drive-called-iis-does-not-exist). Is the module actually installed on your computer?

Comment: My web.config file have a different name( lets say settings.config) but the aspnet_regiis.exe only able to encrypt or decrypt <connection string> from web.config so how to make it encrypt < connectionstring> from my renamed web.config(settings.config)